# IPhone state from sound mode to silent/vibrate mode

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to develop an iOS app which on button tapped  the phone state from sound mode to  silent/vibrate mode . how to do it??

Comment: You can't. The vibrate phone state is that indicated by the button on the side of the phone and no way in hell will Apple let you mess this up.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official/legal/acceptable by Apple way to accomplish what you want. However, if you are still interested you should check private libraries for the app for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Please, consider leaving a comment explaning your reason for downvoting before/after downvoting. Thank you!

Comment: I did not say it's not possible, please, read carefully. And, I couldn't find the app named "Silent Time" on the app store that has silent mode on/off feature, could you please post a link?. Also, it's worth to note that sometimes apps those use private libraries reach the App Store (human factor, I think), and it doesn't mean that you can do the same.